# Rotate table DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have a small table, one row, three columns. I need it to be one column three rows.

Thanks,
Buzkie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a small table, why not use a UNION?

```
SELECT new_column_name
    FROM (
    SELECT col1 AS new_column_name
    FROM   table
    UNION
    SELECT col2
    FROM   table
    UNION
    SELECT col3
    FROM   table
) AS new_table
```

For larger tables, you could use the approach described in MarkW's post.  The DB2 function COALESCE() gives the same functionality as ISNULL() in those SQL Server examples.

Comment: it ended up working. It was just a pain due to the way each of the columns were pulled. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for [SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175574).  I suspect it might work for DB2.

Comment: I found that one. That is just taking a column and filtering it to make new ones, column to rows. I need row to columns

Comment: I think I understand what you are looking for then.  It seems to me that Martin's answer is the correct one.